# Python Left merge with right DF larger than left DF

Tags: python, merge, vlookup

I have been looking for a solution for a python version of excel´s VLookup.
I have a left DF that has let's say 10,000 rows, and a right DF that has 20,000 rows.
I need to match the 10,000 in my original Left DF with corresponding values in the Right DF and add columns and their matching values to each row, but python keeps adding rows to the merged DF. I have seen the explanations for why this is, but need to find a solution so this does not happen. I have seen all the answers about using duplicate or drop_duplicate methods, but the entire purpose of this exercise is to highlight duplicates, so those don't work here.

The script I have is (something like):

```
DF1=pd.merge(left=DF1, right=DF2, how='left', left_on='col_B', right_on='col_3')
```

I have also tried all variations of this same script:

```
DF1.merge(DF2, how='left', left_on='col_B', right_on='col_3', inplace=True) 
DF_Merged= pd.merge(left=DF1, right=DF2, how='left', left_on='col_B', right_on='col_3')
DF_merged=DF1.merge(DF2, how='left', left_on='col_B', right_on='col_3')
```

etc., etc., etc.

In all and any cases, my original DF1 goes from 10,000 rows to 15,000 rows, when I need it to stay the same length, just add the info from the DF2 to those existing 10,000 rows whose values match col_B and col_3, just as a VLookup would in excel.

I have a few of these coming up, so would be great to find a python fix for this.

Any help would be super appreciated :-)

Comment: Try including 'left_index'=True in your original script.

Comment: You can't include both left_on and a left_index parameters.